# why do I get a black page?

Tags: html, vbscript

According to this [link](http://www.tizag.com/vbscriptTutorial/vbscriptfirstscript.php) if I create an html file like the one below, I should get a hello world on the webpage

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/vbscript">
document.write("Hello World")
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

so I did and opened the file in my browser but I can't see anything, is vbscript no longer supported or do I have to enable anything in my browser

similar example [here](https://sites.google.com/site/vbscriptcsctraining/home/adding-vbscript-code-to-an-html-page) yet no results

why isn't this working

Comment: Are you hosting this page on a webserver? Modern browsers don't allow scripts from local html files.

Comment: Modern browsers don't support VBScript regardless of whether it’s running locally or in a web server. Not surprisingly as the links you reference are over 10 years old at least.